# User.IsInRole returns false after switching to one role per user

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-identity

After switching from default AspNetRole many-to-many relation to one role per user, and created a custom identity role, User.IsInRole("Admin") is always returning false.

The user signed in is seeded in the DB context, while i deleted and seeded the user again to match one-role per user.

Heres the app user:

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   // person props

    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    public ApplicationIdentityRole Role { get; set; }
}
```

And the identity:

```cs
 public class ApplicationIdentityRole : IdentityRole<string>
 {
     public List<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUser { get; set; }
 }
```

Here is my DBContext:

```cs
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationIdentityRole, string>
 {
    // DBSets..

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    { 
         string ADMIN_ID = _config.GetValue<string>("Tokens:SysUsers:Admin");

         string ADMIN_ROLE_ID = _config.GetValue<string>("Tokens:Roles:Admin");

         builder.Entity<ApplicationIdentityRole>().HasData(new ApplicationIdentityRole
            {
                Id = ADMIN_ROLE_ID,
                Name = "Admin",
                NormalizedName = "ADMIN"
            });

            var hasher = new PasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>();

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasData(new ApplicationUser
            {
                Id = ADMIN_ID,
                UserName = "admin",
                NormalizedUserName = "ADMIN",
                Email = "admin@sys.com",
                NormalizedEmail = "ADMIN@SYS.COM",
                EmailConfirmed = true,
                PasswordHash = hasher.HashPassword(null, "123123"),
                SecurityStamp = string.Empty,
                Title = "Admin",
                RoleId = ADMIN_ROLE_ID
            });
    }
}
```

And i have changed the startup to match the app identity role class:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationIdentityRole>()
                         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                         .AddDefaultTokenProviders()
                         .AddDefaultUI();

services.AddTransient<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Login:

```cs
// sigin manager
private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

// usage
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

Authorization is working perfectly, but the **role is always returning false**.

I realized that inheriting from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationIdentityRole, string>` generates the default roles table (many-to-many) so theoretically, it will consider the added Role property to the user just a dataset `AspNetRole` and validate the many-to-many table not the `RoleId`.

I couldn't find any documentation that covers how to set one-role per user using ef.

**Any help is really appreciated!**

**Update**: on successful sign-in, the role is not added to the claims by the SignInManager but only added when there is a record in the `AspNetUserRole` (many-to-many) table which I want to exclude.

Answer (score 0):

> Authorization is working perfectly, but the role is always returning
> false.

That's because the sign-in process will look for role data through the `AspNetUserRole` table, and you did not insert any data in that table.

You can extend the Identity models, but you cannot modify the relationships among them. To find the options you have to customize `Identity` models, take a look at [Identity model customization in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

The changes you've made will not affect the default many-to-many relationship between `User` and `Role` (take a look at your database, and you'll still find the joining table `AspNetUserRole`). And the built-in functionalities of `UserManager`, `RoleManager`, `SignInManager` etc will continue to work based on that default relationship.

**For your current scenario:**
With your custom relationship, you have to use custom approach to access Role data. Instead of `User.IsInRole("Admin")` you have to do something like -

```cs
var user = context.ApplicationUsers.Include(p=> p.ApplicationIdentityRole).FirstOrDefault(p=> p.UserName == User.Identity.Name);
var isInRole = user.ApplicationIdentityRole.Name == "Admin";
```

And if you want `one-role per user`, there's no need to create the extra relation and increase the complexity. You can simply add a property named `Role` in your `ApplicationUser` model -

```cs
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

This way you still have to use your own approach to access Role data (since you are not using the many-to-many relationship), but it will be easier now -

```cs
var isInRole = context.ApplicationUsers.FirstOrDefault(p=> p.UserName == User.Identity.Name && p=> p.Role == "Admin");
```

**For a better solution:**
For now, you are creating User and Role via data-seeding. But normally you would want to add new Role to a User with something like -

```cs
await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
```

and this would put Role linking data in the `AspNetUserRole` table and that data will be used by the sign-in process, and you would have expected result from `User.IsInRole("Admin")` method.

So, if you really want to restrict the Users to have only one Role, while everything to work as expected, you just need make sure that more than one role cannot be added to a User. You can do that by -

1. Deriving from `UserManager<ApplicationUser>` class and then overriding the `AddToRoleAsync` method. But for you purpose, it will be an overkill.
2. Doing the following -

```cs
if ((await userManager.GetRolesAsync(user)).Count == 0)
{
    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
}
```